# Internal property and subclassing

Tags: c#

I think it is by design and there is nothing can be done about it, but I found it interesting.

I needed to create a concreate class based on third-party abstract base class. As always, I told Visual Studio to implement abstract base class, which it did, but the code didn't compile complaining about missing getter. However, event after adding getter manualy, the code still didn't compile. It turned out that this getter is internal. Funny thing about internal property is that it's not shown in metadata (View Definition). Vendor will make it protected in the next release, but at the time being, unless I'm missing some other way, there is nothing I can do about it, right?

-Stan

Comment: I see lots of English but no C#...

Comment: Pretty much, right ... nothing you can do about it. Good thing the vendor will fix for the next release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct.

In fact, we basically [do the same thing in Noda Time](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/03/the-curious-case-of-the-publicity-seeking-interface-and-the-shy-abstract-class.aspx) where we want to expose a type (`CalendarSystem`) so that clients can pass calendars around - but all the actual interaction is internal to the library, using other internal types. What you've got as a problem in your situation is actually a blessing in ours, as it means we can keep more of the implementation internal and hidden :)

It's harder to do the same thing with interfaces...